# array.prototype.reduce: Pushing string value to empty array within arrow function

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I have the following code that reduces the array to numbers without the letter 'e'

```
var numbers = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six",
               "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven"];
var reduced = numbers.reduce(function(reducedArray, number) { 
  if (number.toString().indexOf("e") === -1) {
    reducedArray.push(number); 
  }
  return reducedArray; 
}, []);
```

Everything is working fine. But now i want the same code in an arrow-function

```
var reduced = numbers.reduce((reducedArray, number) => {
  if (number.indexOf('e') === -1) {
    reducedArray.push(number);
  }
}, []);
```

But this doesn't work, because the `reducedArray` is undefined and I couldn't find any solution to this.

Comment: you need to return it

Comment: `var reduced = numbers.reduce(((reducedArray, number) => (number.indexOf('e') === -1 && reducedArray.push(number),reducedArray) ),[]);`

Comment: Why do you want it as an arrow function, when it's so much more difficult to read?

Comment: @ Pranav C Balan Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not work because you don't return the array. But you should use `filter` instead:

```js
var numbers = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six",
               "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven"];
var reduced = numbers.filter(number => !number.includes("e"));
console.log(reduced);
```